# Global functions in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a way where I can define global functions so I can share the implementation across multiple views.

I was wondering where would I place them? I tried _viewStart.cshtml and /Share/_Layout.cshtml but It seems that is not working.

I don't want to create an Extension to the `HtmlHelper` class. In my case, extensions won't work. I hate to keep copying the same function in multiple views.

```
@functions  {
  public static string GetColumnHeader(string columnName, string columnHeader, ISupportGridViewModel model)
  {
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", columnHeader, model.Sort == columnName ? model.SortDir == "ASC" ? "▲" : "▼" : string.Empty);
  }
}
```

For those who commented that I should use extension. Here is the example where I am not able to to get it to work. As far as I know, Razor helpers are nothing more than extension methods and It won't work.

Here is an example that is working

```
    var grid = new WebGrid(this.Model.Data);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.Numeric);
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table grid",
                  columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column(columnName: "Time", format: (item) => MethodDefinedInView(item.EndTime))
  ))
```

Here is an example that doesn't work...

```
var grid = new WebGrid(this.Model.Data);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.Numeric);
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table grid",
              columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column(columnName: "Time", format: (item) => Html.ExtensionMethod(item.EndTime))
```

))

Comment: Why won't extensions work? that looks like a good candidate for an extension.

Comment: What makes you think _extensions won't work_?

Comment: I am using MVC webgrid and the when you want to pass an extension as ( Func<dynamic, object> format), It fails. It doesn't like extensions here. 

So, The only way that I was able to resolve it by invoking a function instead.

Comment: If you can use the function above, then you can certainly create a HtmlHelper method that does the same - something like `@Html.ColumnHeader(columnName, ....)`

Comment: perhaps you can use a razor helper instead, you can read about them here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor .  It also includes information on how to reuse them.  Your problem with reuse is probably that you're making the function static.

Comment: I Updated the question. Extension methods  are not working.

Comment: @Sam - razor helpers are not extension methods.

Comment: When I think of razor helpers, i think of Html.TextBox/TextBoxFor/DropDownFor/etc. Those are helpers and they are extensions methods to the HtmlHelper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a static method in a Utilities class. You can access that in your view by either adding a reference to the namespace in the Web.config inside the Views folder, or just at the top of each cshtml file.

Comment: Can you explain more, with example? I want to reuse helpers like old version(App_Code), in new mvc.