# Global Function in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create global function, but I have an error in mycode like this :

```
public static GetTotalResearchByArea()
{
    var listOfStrings = new List<int>();
    var all_area = context.Areas.Select(x => x.Id ).ToList();

    foreach( var item in all_area)
    {
        var allReserachCategory = context.ResearchCategories
                                         .Where(a => a.AreaId == item)
                                         .Select(a => a.Id).ToList();

        var totalResearchBySingleArea = context.Researchs
                  .Where(c => allReserachCategory.Contains(c.ResearchCategoryId)).Count();

        listOfStrings.Add(totalResearchBySingleArea);
    }
    return listOfStrings;
}
```

what should it be ?

Comment: It seems that you have not set the type of `GetTotalResearchByArea`. You need to have it to be something like `public static Task<List<int>> GetTotalResearchByArea()` and then `return Task.FromResult(listOfStrings);`. It could also just return a `List<int>` straight on - `public static List<int> GetTotalResearchByArea`.

Comment: ok thanks alot, I will try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global functions in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262259/global-functions-in-mvc-5)

Answer (score 3):

alhamdulillaah solved..

```
public Array GetTotalResearchByArea()
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    var all_area = context.Areas.Select(x => x.Id ).ToList();

    foreach( var item in all_area)
    {
        var allReserachCategory = context.ResearchCategories.Where(a => a.AreaId == item).Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
        var totalResearchBySingleArea = context.Researchs.Where(c => allReserachCategory.Contains(c.ResearchCategoryId)).Count();
        list.Add(totalResearchBySingleArea);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Who's "alhamdulillaah"?

Comment: Please use a typed array, that makes working with the result so much easier

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining something its better to use IList than List<> . As an answer for your question I would prefer to use

```
public static IList<int> GetTotalResearchByArea(){
 //write your codes as usual
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning string from the function but there is no return type of function update code like this:

```
public static List<int> GetTotalResearchByArea()
{ 
    // here put your code
}
```

Hope it helps.